# setTimeout firing too soon(?)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

Alright, right now I'm writing a little JavaScript code that I can just simply copy paste into the Firefox Console and run. (I'm sorry, I'm still a massive noob, and I want to write a little script that basically, opens a certain web page and collects information form certain divs in it.)

However, I'm struggling at the moment. I would like to open a certain webpage, and then, after it is entirely loaded, execute a certain function. (for simplyfying reasons, this function just counts from 0 to 99.)

```
function openGroupsPage() {

 window.location.replace(groupURL);

 setTimeout(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
 } , 10000)
}


openGroupsPage()
```

**My problem is** : The incrementing function never gets called (or atleast it seems like it because i can never see any kind of output in the console.) Why is my setTimeout not working or what is another option to accomplish what I would like to do? I would just really like to run a specific function when the newly accessed website is finished loading entirely.

Comment: Well it's not gone trigger because the first thing you do is to redirect to a new page. The timer needs to be on that "groupUrl" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the location, the window object and all of its associated things (including timers) are discarded and a new one created. You can't schedule code to run in the new document from within the old document (not even from the browser console). You'll have to paste and execute your code *after* navigating to the new page, not before, which means you can't navigate to it from within your code.

You might look at tools like TamperMonkey or GreaseMonkey and such that let you run code in response to pages loading that match certain URLs.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.replace()` exits the current page and loads a new one. So any remaining JavaScript of the current page isn't executed anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working fine the only problem is `window.localtion` line reload the website with the url you provided so the entire page is getting reload from start and your page lost your function.

***try the below to understand***

```
function openGroupsPage() {

 //window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');

 setTimeout(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
 } , 1000)
}


openGroupsPage()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add an eventListener do the document of the page which fires when the page is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' function(e) {
  // page is loaded do you fancy stuff in here 
  // no timeout needed
});
```

EDIT: Overlooked that he want to do it over the console on a random page. This won't work because on locationchange all current scripts are stopped and global objects are destroyed.

Use something like `Greasemonkey` for that.